# Obtain Recepient Email Address (To address) from Outlook Plugin

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-addin

am trying to find the Recepient To email address,while reading mails from outlook i have tried these things, but am getting all the recepients including the cc,but i only need to email address in mailitem

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail in myInbox.Items)
{
        string smtpAddress = string.Empty;
        Subject = mail.Subject;
        Description = mail.Body;
        FromEmail = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients recips = mail.Recipients;
        string mailids = string.Empty;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recip in recips)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = recip.PropertyAccessor;
            smtpAddress = pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E").ToString();
            ToEmail = smtpAddress;
            break;
        }
        MailedDateTime = mail.CreationTime;
        Direction = 1;
        CompanyID = CompanyID;
        UserID = UserID;
        ID = mail.EntryID;
}
```

and i have also tried

```
ToEmail = mail.To;
```

in this am getting the name of recepient sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Recipient class to detect the To recipients only. It will be one of the following OlMailRecipientType constants: olBCC, olCC, olOriginator, or **olTo**. It looks like you need to check out the Type property.

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: yes,olTo worked for me  if (recip.Type == (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo){}. this check gives the to mailaddress, Thanks.